# Email send to friend functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a mail-to-friend function from my Home Page so when the user clicks the email image their client opens up and has the title and message body already filled in. Any help would be appreciated?

```
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png"), "http://www.facebook.com/site" %>
<%= link_to image_tag ("twitter.png"), "http://twitter.com/#!/site" %>
<%= link_to image_tag "email.png" ???? %>
```

Comment: Looking at this, you might as well want to have a look at a ready widget like http://www.addthis.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best way to achieve this according to the Rails api:

```
mail_to "me@domain.com"
# => <a href="mailto:me@domain.com">me@domain.com</a>
```

Full documentation at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to

Answer (score 0):

Use a mailto tag
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

Syntax here: http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html

Comment: These are html - I am looking for a Rails specific method to achieve this, similar to the examples I listed above?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails. Try this: `<%= link_to image_tag("email.png"), "mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" %>`